# Set Private NuGet Feed API Key on Mac OS X

Tags: .net, macos, nuget

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Mac OS X to create a .NET Core application. I'd like to package and push this artifact to our internal, private NuGet feed, which is secured via an API key. According to the [NuGet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file), there's a `setapikey` sub-command on the NuGet binary to configure an encrypted API key in a local `nuget.config` file.

However, the NuGet binary isn't available on Mac OS X.

```
➜  dncore11 nuget
zsh: command not found: nuget
```

Here's the output from `dotnet --info`:

```
➜  dncore11 dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.1)

Product Information:
Version:            1.0.1
Commit SHA-1 hash:  005db40cd1

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Mac OS X
OS Version:  10.12
OS Platform: Darwin
RID:         osx.10.12-x64
Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1
```

**Question**: Given the above, how do I set the NuGet API key for an internal feed on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have the .NET Core SDK installed then you can run nuget with:

```
dotnet nuget
```

Unfortunately the nuget that is included with the .NET Core SDK does not support the setapikey argument. So I think you are going to be left with downloading [nuget.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) and installing Mono so you can run that executable and use the setapikey.